# Eslint error went passing array into function and using map on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am getting the linting error

```
Must use destructuring files assignment  react/destructuring-assignment
```

For the code below

```
const showFiles = label => (files) =>  
  (   
    <>
      {files.map(({ name }, index) => (
        <Typography key={`${label}-file-${index}`}>{name}</Typography>     
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

I tried changing it to this

```
const showFiles = label => ({ map }) =>
  (
    <>
      {map(({ name }, index) => (
        <Typography key={`${label}-file-${index}`}>{name}</Typography>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

This makes the linting error go away but then the actual webpage has the following error.

```
TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

Is there a way around this linting error that I am not seeing? Do I have to use `Array.prototypes.map` or something?

Comment: Why don't you disable the lint rule for this function? Destructuring here reduces readability. *What* are you mapping? *What* does this function take?

Comment: Could you share your eslintrc? Take a look at the rule here https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md

Comment: it's a shared project and I don't have a say in the enforced linting rules. If there isn't a way around it I will try to figure out how to rearrange my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing it to

```
const showFiles = label => field => (
  <>
    {Array.prototype.map.call(field, ({ name }, index) => (
      <Typography key={`${label}-file-${index}`}>{name}</Typography>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

It works and the linting error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The `rest` parameters and `spread` operators in ES6 would be a great use in this case. In the function `showFiles`, changing the `files` to `...files` implies the function is expecting an array type argument, which improves readability and linting process.

For example

```
const showFiles = label => (...files) => {
    return (   
      <>
      {files.map(({ name }, index) => (
        <Typography key={`${label}-file-${index}`}>{name}</Typography>     
      ))}
    </>
    );
  }
```

And add the `spread` operators when calling the function

```
  return (
    <>
      {
        showFiles('fileLabel')(...[
         {name:'a'},
         {name:'b'}
        ])
      }
      
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method want to iterate over each element of your array. So let your callback function be :

`files.map(item => <Typography>{item.name}</Typography>)`

Comment: I am doing that in my original code. I actually only unpacked `name` afterward hoping that that is the issue the lint error was pointing out but no such luck. It is complaining about `files` not being deconstructed. I know what `map` does. I only tried the second method to see if it made the lint error go away and hoped against hope that it would unpack it as the map function attached to the array prototype but doesn't seem to be the case.